# How do I show that the equation E(k) = 2-4cos(ka) is a parabola when k=0 and when k=pi/a?

Tags: conic-sections

It's evident from the graph but I'm not sure how to show this mathematically. This dispersion relation is supposed to be roughly parabolic

Comment: What? $$\;E(0)=2-4\cos (0)=2-4=-2\;,\;\;E\left(\frac\pi a\right)=2-4\cos\pi=2+4=6$$ The two above are numbers, not parabolas...

Comment: It is parabola shaped at the min and max, but the equation gives numbers the same as you got DonAntonio which is why I was confused, I don't know how to say it's a parabola
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D+2-+4cos%284k%29+from+-2pi%2F4+to+2pi%2F4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost any minimum or maximum will be approximately parabolic.  You can calculate the Taylor series at $(x_0,y_0)$ and get $y \approx y_0+y'(x_0)(x-x_0)+y''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2\dots$  Since you are at a minimum or maximum, you have $y'(x_0)=0$ so that term goes away.  The higher order terms are small when you are near the minimum or maximum.  In your case of $y=2-4 \cos (4x)$, one minimum is $(0,-2)$ and the Taylor series is $y \approx -2+32x^2-\frac {128}3x^4+\dots$  For $|x| \ll 1$ you can ignore the quartic and higher terms.